# How can I check if a file is forbidden in C?

Tags: c, file, http, io

Basically I'm working on a html server assignment and part of the assignment is giving an "error 403 FORBIDDEN" message and although I know how to check if the file exist how can I check if its forbidden.

What I'm doing is this for opening a file.

```
File* filein = fopen(pathname,"r");
```

Just let me know what I can do to check if the file is forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen()` returns a null pointer if it fails. Depending on the library implementation, the global variable `errno` may be set to indicate the cause of failure.

Usually, invalid file permissions will cause an `EACCES` error, so after a failed `fopen()`, check if `errno` is equal to `EACCES` (remember to `#include <errno.h>`). If not, it may be unopenable due to some other error unrelated to file permissions.

[Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/errno.h.html)'s a page with some other error constants you could check for.

Comment: do I just check simply by doing something like if(errno==EACCES) after the attempted fopen?

Comment: Yes, that's correct; `errno` is an integer, so you would compare the error code the same way you would with any other integer.

Answer (score 1):

forbidden files are unacessable i think (for example chmod 440 set as user that isn't running server), so when you can't open file due to lack of permission you can inform user about that, example code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        perror("Error");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

remember to make file unable to access - for example `chmod 000 file.txt`

Comment: you can check errno value, just remember to import errno.h. check different error codes with `printf("%d", errno);`. if there's no such file error code is 2 and if you have no permissions to open it error code is 13 or like you just asked, `if(errno==EACCES)` will also work